# Buy and Sell stocks twice

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I am working on understanding this [problem](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/leetcode-best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iii-java/) where I need to find out the max profit when I am allowed to buy/sell stocks at most twice. The provided solution talks about maintaining price difference array from left to right and that makes sense to me. However the post also talks about maintaining another array of price difference from right to left and I am not able to understand that logic as why does that gives profit after the first transaction.

```
Prices= [1, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 2, 9]
left  = [0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8]
right = [8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0]
max_profit = 13
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that there are two arrays in the proposed solution that you mentioned is related to the constraint of the problem that allows using only 2 transactions.

As also specified, the transactions should not be intercalated -- *i.e.* one transaction should be before (to the left of) the other one (which will be to the right).

More specifically, the two arrays in the proposed solution represent the following:

- left[i] = the best transaction that can be made by buying and selling in the interval [0, i]. If selling is done at time j (with j in [0, i]), the buy should be done at the minimum price from 0 to j.
- right[i] = the best transaction that can be made by buying and selling in the interval [i, n-1]. If buying is done at time j (with j in [i, n-1]), the selling should be done at the maximum price from j to n-1.

All that needs to be found is a good separation point, *i*, of the two transactions. Then the best combination will involve the profit left[i] + right[i], and this can be found by trying all possible *i* values.

Comment: *Then the best combination will involve the profit left[i] + right[i]*, shouldn't it be `left[i - 1] + right[i]` as we combine the maximum profit made for the previous day and the maximum profit made by selling on the current day?

Comment: @Brayoni that is a good point. Notice that by using left[i] + right[i] instead of the cleaner left[i - 1] + right[i] only risks to take into account apparently invalid solutions where we sell the first stock at the time of buying the second one. However that kind of situation is not actually invalid, since it is in fact equivalent to performing a single transaction. The statement mentions that we are allowed to use _at most_ two transactions (i.e. a single transaction is valid, too), this is why the official solution with left[i] + right[i] also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the problem as DP, make first set case where you are not buying and selling the stocks so the first profit will be zero, make the profit in same sequence

**When only one transaction is made**

Track the array and maintain the minimum of the number with previous price the max profit is max number - min number in the array. so problem is basically finding max and min in an array and difference will be the maximum profit, here we just updating the profit array as to what is maximum profit till that particular day is transaction in made or not. This array will be used as the usage of data in the further transaction is asked.

```
// Condition for the only one transaction is possible
       for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
         min = Math.min(price[i - 1], min);
           profit[i] = Math.max(profit[i - 1], price[i] - min);
        }
```

**If at most two transaction can be made**

Now here the thing is tricky, we have to just keep the track of any previous computations made for the max profit made till that dat for k-1 transaction (here k=2). The problem can be made a dynamic problem for any number of the transactions.

```
profit for a particular day is = max{ if no transaction is made (Then previous max profit, ie profit[i - 1]),
previous_profit + Max of sale possible{present price - all previous price(i,i-1,...0))
```

**For k=2**

```
//   Condition for at most two transaction is possible
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
           max = Math.max(max, profit[i] - price[i]);
             profit[i] = Math.max(profit[i - 1], max + price[i]);
        }
```

**Here is general code for k transactions**
We just need two array to track the previous profit value and override on each iteration. It can also be done using 2-D array still we don't need any previous data so I made it with even and positive data array

```
   package DynamicProblems;

    public class StockSales {

        private static int maxProfit(int price[], int n, int k) {
            int currentProfit[] = new int[n];
            int previousProfit[];
            int evenProfit[] = new int[n];
            int oddProfit[] = new int[n];

            for (int t = 0; t <= k - 1; t++) {
                int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                if (t % 2 == 1) {
                    currentProfit = oddProfit;
                    previousProfit = evenProfit;
                } else {
                    currentProfit = evenProfit;
                    previousProfit = oddProfit;
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                    max = Math.max(max, previousProfit[i - 1] - price[i - 1]);
                    currentProfit[i] = Math.max(currentProfit[i - 1], max + price[i]);
                }
            }
            return currentProfit[n - 1];
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            int price[] = {3, 4, 10, 103};
            int k = 1;
            int n = price.length;
            System.out.println("\nMaximum Profit = " + maxProfit(price, n, k));
        }
    }
```